# Using Wallpaper Shuffle with a set order (iOS 16)

Tags: ios, screen-lock, wallpaper

I want to use Wallpaper Shuffle (iOS lock screen photo shuffle) to show a carousel of images, but they are being shown in a random order. This isn't very functional.   Is there any way to turn this off or make a shortcut?

I'm using “change on tap.”

Comment: Change on tap? Are you on a macOS device or iOS device?

Comment: @IconDaemon I'm on iOS 16.3 I think

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use wallpaper shuffle to show a carousel of images but mine is in a random order..

**It’s working as expected**.  Per [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200285) one of the Wallpaper options is a *Photo Shuffle* and provides instructions on how to create a gallery of photos to use.

From Merriam-Webster, the definition of [Shuffle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shuffle):  *to mix in a mass confusedly; jumble*

When you select *Shuffle* it will give you the items, in this case wallpaper images/backgrounds in random order.

> is there any way to turn this off

Not presently.

> or make a shortcut

It definitely possible for a shortcut to *rotate* iOS wallpaper and there are many, [many existing tutorials and articles](https://www.bing.com/search?q=ios%20shortcut%20random%20wallpaper&pc=EMMX04&FORM=EMMXA2&mkt=en-us) on how to do so.